# R check for multiple conditions and transform from column to row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following table:

| id | action | fun | history | usefulness | intention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | 5 | 1 | Strongly Agree | Agree |
| b | 5 | 3 | 4 | Agree | Agree |
| c | 3 | 3 | 4 | Agree | Disagree |
| d | 4 | 3 | 5 | Neutral | Agree |
| e | 1 | 3 | 4 | Agree | Agree |

Now I want to be every row where action, `fun` or `history` is above 3 to be a single row. It means that if `action`, `fun` or `history` are all above 3, it should be three rows. The entry with ID `a` should be two rows (`action` and `fun` above 3, `history` below 3) and look like below:

| id | type | usefulness | intention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | action | Strongly Agree | Agree |
| a | fun | Strongly Agree | Agree |
| b | fun | Agree | Agree |
| b | history | Agree | Agree |
| c | history | Agree | Disagree |

In the end I would like to have a likert plot like this:
[image: Example Plot]

With `type` as car brands and two groups (`usefulness`, `intention`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `tidyr` mixed solution;

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("action", "fun", "history"), names_to = "type") %>%
  filter(value > 3) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  relocate(type, .after = id)
```

output;

```
  id    type    usefulness     intention
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>          <chr>    
1 a     action  Strongly Agree Agree    
2 a     fun     Strongly Agree Agree    
3 b     action  Agree          Agree    
4 b     history Agree          Agree    
5 c     history Agree          Disagree 
6 d     action  Neutral        Agree    
7 d     history Neutral        Agree    
8 e     history Agree          Agree
```

---

data;

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), action = c(4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 1L), fun = c(5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), history = c(1L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), usefulness = c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
"Neutral", "Agree"), intention = c("Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", 
"Agree", "Agree")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Just one more question in this context. What do I have to add to your suggested command when I have instead of "Strong Agree", "Agree",... numbers from 1 to 5 in order to plot it with: `plot(likert(df))`

Comment: this should be a separate question